# How to Assign List to a variable based on a condition in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I have to POST customer details (list hardcode just for reff) and also I want to POST a list with unique ID.

I have written a simple For loop which adds customer details to the List only if my details to be POSTED have a unique Id, but I'm getting an error here which says "Not all code path returns a value". Please tell me if there is another simple way.

```
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    public CustomerController()
    {
        customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "1", FirstName = "Batman", LastName = "Gotham", DOB = "17/04/1978", SSN = "1000000000" });
        customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "2", FirstName = "Superman", LastName = "Krypton", DOB = "18/04/1938", SSN = "2000000000" });
        customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "3", FirstName = "Wonder Woman", LastName = "Themyscira", DOB = "22/03/1976", SSN = "3000000000" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        int n = customers.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (customer.Id != customers[i].Id)
            {
                customers.Add(customer);
                string msg = "done";
                return Ok(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do in the code. The error is clear in a sense that in the `Post` method… what happens if the line of code… `if (customer.Id != customers[i].Id) {…` never evaluates to `true` ? what is returned in that case? This is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the *"Not all code path returns a value"* error, because the method may end without the control flow entering the if-statement at all. You need to return something after the end of the loop. E.g., `return BadRequest(msg);`

But your logic is flawed anyway. You add the customer as soon as you find an Id in the list that is different, but there might be a customer with the same Id further down the list.

Also, you do not have to implement the search for the Id yourself. Just use the existing [Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0).

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
    if (customers.Any(c => c.Id == customer.Id)) {
        string msg = "duplicate";
        return BadRequest(msg);
    } else {
        string msg = "done";
        customers.Add(customer);
        return Ok(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method need to return something every time (`return null` will work too), so when the return is in `if` statement, it may not enter that if statement on all of the loop's iterations therefore not `return` anything, so you need to have another `return` either in `else` statement, or outside of the `if` statement.